# How do you find the correct verb names to use with FolderItem.InvokeVerb?

Tags: winapi, windows-shell

How does one find the exact verbs to be used with the Windows API function `FolderItem.InvokeVerb`? The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folderitem-invokeverb#parameters) says, "It must be one of the values returned by the item's `FolderItemVerb.Name` property." However, this does not seem to be true.

Using a folder as an example, if you run this on Windows 10 (using PowerShell):

```
$Shell = New-Object -ComObject 'Shell.Application'
$Shell.NameSpace('C:\Windows').Self.Verbs()
```

you will get a list that looks like this:

```
Application Parent Name
----------- ------ ----
                   &Open
                   Pin to Quick access
                   Scan with Microsoft Defender...
```

... and so on.

Those Names are what you get in an Explorer context menu, but they do not work with `InvokeVerb`. For some of them, such as `&Open`, all you have to do is remove the `&`. For others, such as `Pin to Quick access`, the actual verb that works is altogether different (`pintohome`). How can one reliably find these "actual" verbs for an arbitrary item?

I have found that the verbs that do work with `InvokeVerb` correspond to the sub-keys that you can find in the Registry under `HKCR\<class name>\shell`. However, even knowing that does not make things simple. I have found some verbs before by searching `HKCR` for the string returned by `FolderItemVerb.Name`, but that doesn't work if the string is localized. If you happen to know the name of the class, you could look there directly. (Using the folder example, `pintohome` is one of the keys under `HKCR\Folder\shell`.) However, when it is localized, there is nothing there that directly indicates this is the verb you are looking for, so you have to try it to find out. And, if you are inside some special shell folder or namespace extension, you might not know what class name(s) to even go looking for.

Comment: Yes, this scripting library API is old and has lots of problems, shortcomings, etc. as well as its documentation. Name is the text string, not the verb. The list of available verbs (you can have one verb max per menu item, some items don't have a verb) is not static, it's composed dynamically when the context menu is built by the Shell, and as the name says, it's depends on context (Explorer, 3rd party app and extensions, etc.). Getting the exact list is more complex than it looks and requires native API calls. Once you know a verb like "pintohome", then it's stable, won't vary per language

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/fa-verbs#shortcut-menu-verbs):Verbs can also have a display name associated with them, which is displayed on the shortcut menu instead of the verb string itself. For example, the display string for openas is Open With. Like normal menu strings, including an `ampersand character(&)` in the display string allows keyboard selection of the command.So & means that you can use the keyboard to select. What `FolderItemVerb.Name` returns is not the verb identifier, but the display name associated with the verb.

Comment: I will confirm with the internal engineer about the problem described in the document, and response here if there is any update. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @SimonMourier So is implementing a context menu like Raymond Chen describes [in this OldNewThing blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040920-00/?p=37823) the only way to get the actual verbs? I have written native code before just to access some shell APIs but this `IContextMenu` business looks more complicated than I was hoping for.

Comment: You don't need all of what's described in the 11 articles, but yes, you'll have to initialize the menu and then scan for its verb using GetCommandString with GCS_VERBW https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-icontextmenu-getcommandstring maybe it's an XY problem. Why do you need to find all verbs?

Comment: Two things prompted the question. 1) I have a few times worked on something that somehow involved verbs and it just seems overly complex to find them sometimes. 2) Current project was identifying whether RDS users have a non-standard folder pinned to Quick Access and the simplest thing I came up with that I could script quickly was enumerating the Quick Access folder and identifying which items had the 'Unpin' option. But since I couldn't find a way to get the actual verbs, I had to rely on localized strings. Fortunately not many languages to deal with in this case.