# ShellFolderItem COM Object InvokeVerbEx method - How/where can I find a list of verb arguments (vArgs) for a given verb?

Tags: com

While this question isn't specific to any language, I'm using PowerShell to explore COM objects/interfaces for what it's worth.

I'm looking at the documentation for the [ShellFolderItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shellfolderitem-object) object's [InvokeVerbEx method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/invokeverbex) -- specifically the 2nd parameter, vArgs.  The documentation states:

> vArgs [in, optional]
>
> Type: Variant
>
> A Variant that consists of a string with one or more arguments to the
> command specified by vVerb. The format of this string depends on the
> particular verb.

Exposing the list of applicable verbs is trivial with the [Verbs()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/shell32.folderitem2.verbs?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0#shell32-folderitem2-verbs) method.  Getting a list of arguments that each verb can take has proven to be a dead end so far.  I've googled, read the MS documentation, used tools like oleview.exe and [oleviewdotnot](https://github.com/tyranid/oleviewdotnet), and have looked through various .idl and .h files in the WinSDK, etc and am coming up empty.

Is there a way to programmatically retrieve this information, or is there a website I haven't found that documents the optional arguments for these verbs?

Comment: The Verbs properties exists also on FolderItem instances (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folderitem-verbs) but that won't tell you much more. Most verbs don't take arguments as they just use the contextual shell item(s) and there's no programmatic way to get them (the arguments). The "official" and super limited list is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutew#parameters (edit, open, etc.) but verbs can be implemented by extensions too or are not publicly documented.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66665325/how-do-you-find-the-correct-verb-names-to-use-with-folderitem-invokeverb

Comment: Simon - thanks you for the insights and the link to a helpful stackoverflow question.  Also - a sincere THANK YOU for creating www.magnumdb.com -- I've used this site more times than I can count and it has proven to be an incredibly helpful resource!  :-)